# Can you get a creeper head by a charged creeper by killing it?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can you get you get a creeper head from a charged creeper by killing it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if you can get another charged creeper to kill the creeper. If so, you will get 1 creeper head.

#### Sources

- [Mob head on Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob_head)
- [Creeper on Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper)

Answer (score -2):

No, you must have the creeper explode another creeper.